# Why do successive taps on non-URL URI get ignored even after page reload on Windows Google Chrome?

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, touch, uri

On Windows version of Chrome. After on an already tapped link, every other successive tap on any element with the same URI gets ignored even after a reload of the page.

```html
<p>The following won't have issues with a mouse, but will with a touchscreen on a successive tap within Windows version of Google Chrome:<br /><br />
<strong><a href="tel://tap-on-me-again">tel://tap-on-me-again-within-windows-google-chrome</a></strong>
</p>
```

**Any way to avoid this?** The issue also occurs on Opera, but not Firefox. Have already tried circumvent the issue using JavaScript, to no avail:

```
window.location = "tel://tap-on-me-again"    // click event
```

Comment: Just tested on Google Canary, the issue does not occur on that version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment mentioned Google Canary is now Google Chrome current or later version. Fixed.